# JavaScript Pasar lista a su respectivo div si pertenece a esa clase

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Estoy haciendo una aplicación simple que me ayude a hacer seguimiento de mis pagos, son dos listas que al darle doble clic, pasan a una tercera lista de Pagado. si le doy clic a cada li de Pagado, se pasan a su respectiva lista, Mosquera Ó acapulco. Mi inconveniente es al pasar cada li a su respectiva lista, pues la pasa siempre a la lista acapulco.

[En la pagina oficial de jquery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-has-a-particular-class/) hay un ejemplo, el cual es :

```
$( "div" ).click(function() {
 
    if ( $( this ).hasClass( "protected" ) ) {
 
        $( this )
            .animate({ left: -10 })
            .animate({ left: 10 })
            .animate({ left: -10 })
            .animate({ left: 10 })
            .animate({ left: 0 });
 
    }
 
});
```

En el caso mio quero verificar si el li al que estoy pasando el cursor es de clase acapulco o no, en ese caso me podria el 'li' en la lista acapulco. Si no, en la lista de mosquera. Como muestra el script:

```
$('#done').on('dblclick', 'li', function () {
        if ($('li').hasClass("acapulco")){
            $(this).appendTo('#acapulco')
        }else{
            $(this).appendTo('#mosquera');
        }
```

¿Cúal puede ser mi error en el script?
Gracias.

```js
$(function() {
    function mostrarHora() {
        var fecha = new Date(), // nuevo objeto Fecha
            hora = fecha.getHours() + ":" + fecha.getMinutes() + ":" + fecha.getSeconds();
        $('#hora').text(hora);
    }
    setInterval(mostrarHora, 1000); // la función "mostrarHora" se ejecuta cada segundo
});
// Mosquera - toDo
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mosquera').on('dblclick', 'li', function () {
        $(this).appendTo('#done');
    });

    $('#acapulco').on('dblclick', 'li', function () {
        $(this).appendTo('#done');
    });

    $('#done').on('dblclick', 'li', function () {
        if ($('li').hasClass("acapulco")){
            $(this).appendTo('#acapulco')
        }else{
            $(this).appendTo('#mosquera');
        }
    });

    // $('#done').on('click', 'li', function () {
    //     $(this).appendTo('#acapulco');
    // });
});
//ACAPULCO - toDo
```

```css
a {
    color: #212121;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.list-group-item{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#mosquera>li:hover,.mosquera:hover{
    background-color: #ffc107;
}

#acapulco>li:hover, .acapulco:hover{
    background-color: #007bff;
}

/* #done>li:hover{
    background-color: #28a745;
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=Check.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/pagos.png"/>
    <title>RegistraPagos</title>
</head>

<body class="bg-dark hv-100">
    <div class="container bg-light">
        <div class="relog d-flex justify-content-center">
            
        </div>
        <!-- header -->
        <div class="container bg-danger text-center my-5 text-white ">
            <div class="container-title py-3 mx-2">
                <h2 class="text-center  mb-3" id="title">RegistraPagos!</h2>
                <img src="img/pagos.png" alt="" style="max-width: 200px;">
                <h1 id="hora" style="font-family: ubuntu; font-size: 40px;" class="my-2 "></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <!-- body -->
        <section class="container-fluid ">
            <div class="row" id="lista">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
                    <div class=" container categoria bg-warning p-3">
                        <h3 class="text-center text-uppercase text-white">MOSQUERA</h3>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <ul class="list-group" id="mosquera">
                        <li class="mosquera list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            GAS - 7091578
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mosquera list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            AGUA - 204602
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mosquera list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            ENERGIA - 66160208
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mosquera list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            CLARO - 73864467
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mosquera list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            ADMINISTRACION
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
                    <div class=" container categoria bg-primary p-3">
                        <h3 class="text-center text-uppercase text-white">Acapulco</h3>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <ul class="list-group" id="acapulco">
                        <li class="acapulco list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            GAS - 652659
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="acapulco list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            AGUA - 10337773
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="acapulco list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            ENERGIA - 05606318
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="acapulco list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            ETB - 1434770
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="acapulco list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            MOVISTAR - 3154704298
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="acapulco list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            ADMINISTRACION
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr>                   
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
                    <div class=" container categoria bg-success p-3">
                        <h3 class="text-center text-uppercase text-white">PAGADO</h3>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <ul class="list-group" id="done">

                    </ul>

                 </div>                    
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenías un pequeño problema que pienso que puede ser debido a un despiste:

```
$('#done').on('dblclick', 'li', function () {
    if ($('li').hasClass("acapulco")){
        $(this).appendTo('#acapulco')
    }else{
        $(this).appendTo('#mosquera');
    }
});
```

Cuando preguntas si el `<li>` tiene la clase *acapulco* con `if ($('li').hasClass("acapulco")){` estás preguntando si existe en tu **DOM** un `<li>` que la tenga y como de hecho tienes varios pues siempre se te va a meter por el `TRUE` añadiéndose el item a `#acapulco`.

Lo que debes preguntar en el `if` es si el item que dispara el evento (el `<li>` al que le estás haciendo doble-click) es el que tiene dicha clase o no la tiene. Para ellos debes hacerlo mediante `this` como si que usabas desde dentro de la condición.

```js
$(function() {
    function mostrarHora() {
        var fecha = new Date(), // nuevo objeto Fecha
            hora = fecha.getHours() + ":" + fecha.getMinutes() + ":" + fecha.getSeconds();
        $('#hora').text(hora);
    }
    setInterval(mostrarHora, 1000); // la función "mostrarHora" se ejecuta cada segundo
});
// Mosquera - toDo
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mosquera').on('dblclick', 'li', function () {
        $(this).appendTo('#done');
    });

    $('#acapulco').on('dblclick', 'li', function () {
        $(this).appendTo('#done');
    });

    $('#done').on('dblclick', 'li', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("acapulco")){
            $(this).appendTo('#acapulco')
        }else{
            $(this).appendTo('#mosquera');
        }
    });

    // $('#done').on('click', 'li', function () {
    //     $(this).appendTo('#acapulco');
    // });
});
//ACAPULCO - toDo
```

```css
a {
    color: #212121;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.list-group-item{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#mosquera>li:hover,.mosquera:hover{
    background-color: #ffc107;
}

#acapulco>li:hover, .acapulco:hover{
    background-color: #007bff;
}

/* #done>li:hover{
    background-color: #28a745;
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=Check.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/pagos.png"/>
    <title>RegistraPagos</title>
</head>

<body class="bg-dark hv-100">
    <div class="container bg-light">
        <div class="relog d-flex justify-content-center">
            
        </div>
        <!-- header -->
        <div class="container bg-danger text-center my-5 text-white ">
            <div class="container-title py-3 mx-2">
                <h2 class="text-center  mb-3" id="title">RegistraPagos!</h2>
                <img src="img/pagos.png" alt="" style="max-width: 200px;">
                <h1 id="hora" style="font-family: ubuntu; font-size: 40px;" class="my-2 "></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <!-- body -->
        <section class="container-fluid ">
            <div class="row" id="lista">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
                    <div class=" container categoria bg-warning p-3">
                        <h3 class="text-center text-uppercase text-white">MOSQUERA</h3>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <ul class="list-group" id="mosquera">
                        <li class="mosquera list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            GAS - 7091578
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mosquera list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            AGUA - 204602
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mosquera list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            ENERGIA - 66160208
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mosquera list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            CLARO - 73864467
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mosquera list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            ADMINISTRACION
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
                    <div class=" container categoria bg-primary p-3">
                        <h3 class="text-center text-uppercase text-white">Acapulco</h3>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <ul class="list-group" id="acapulco">
                        <li class="acapulco list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            GAS - 652659
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="acapulco list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            AGUA - 10337773
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="acapulco list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            ENERGIA - 05606318
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="acapulco list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            ETB - 1434770
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="acapulco list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            MOVISTAR - 3154704298
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="acapulco list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            ADMINISTRACION
                            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Check</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr>                   
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
                    <div class=" container categoria bg-success p-3">
                        <h3 class="text-center text-uppercase text-white">PAGADO</h3>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <ul class="list-group" id="done">

                    </ul>

                 </div>                    
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas Gracias. Funciona perfecto.